# Relative path for shared libraries when analysing core dumps

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries, relative-path, coredump

Is it possible to specify relative paths for shared libraries when I do core analysis (I would like to specify relative paths at compile time instead of debug time)

```
(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007f4433ffef00  0x00007f443402cc08  Yes (*)     /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8
0x00007f44334d6a00  0x00007f44335e9920  Yes         /lib/libc.so.6
0x00007f443423eaf0  0x00007f4434257994  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                                        No          ./lib/myplugin.so
                                        No          /opt/lib/mylibc.so
0x00007f443237a190  0x00007f443237d7f8  Yes         /lib/librt.so.1
0x00007f44320f8ef0  0x00007f44321392d8  Yes         /lib/libm.so.6
0x00007f4431ee08b0  0x00007f4431eeffe8  Yes (*)     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
```

I will be more specific about what and why does not work for me:

1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH can specify relative path in respect to Current Working Directory. This does not fit my needs because I need relative path in respect to location of executable
2. RPATH with $ORIGIN is intended to be relative path in respect to location of executable. But it does not fit my needs because it expands to absolute path when I try to do core analysis.

So how can I specify relative path for shared libraries in respect to location of executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that GDB 7.2 currently does not respect RPATH.

There are two bugs opened regarding this issue:
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12250
http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12249

Answer (score 0):

Normally the shared libraries paths don't matter during linking time (unless you're using `rpath`, that keeps the library path in the shared library itself).

When the program is run or debug, the shared libraries are searched in the paths set in shell variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf` (`/etc/ld.so.conf.d/`). `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is with higher priority than `ld.so.conf`.

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../path/to/my/lib1:/path2

It's no problem to use relative path, it will work as well

[Program Library HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)

Comment: But this is relative path in respect to current working directory instead of respect to location of executable, which needs the library.

The problem with -Wl,-R$ORIGIN/../lib is that it anyway expands to absolute path. But this relative path is at least in respect to executable location.